# Forest node with two parts

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, forest

I'm trying to create the following in the forest TikZ-based package:

[image: example graph]

The square nodes require two things I don't know how to do in forest:

- Visually split node into 2 parts, a left and a right
- Have the arrow coming out of the middle of one of the parts to a child (will always be just 1 child)

If there's a way to simply place a node adjacent to another, that would be a possible solution.

Here's what I have so far:

```
\begin{forest}
    [,draw,circle
        [$\lnot B \rvert .$,draw,edge=->
            [,draw,circle,edge=->]
        ]
        [$. \rvert C$,draw,edge=->
            [,draw,circle,edge=->]
        ]
        [$. \rvert \top$,draw,edge=->
            [,draw,circle,edge=->]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
```

Produces this:

[image: graph so far]

Clearly, the vertical bar splitting the rectangular nodes is not tall enough and, most importantly, the arrow coming out of the rectangular nodes are not from the bottom center as opposed to the left or right half of the node.

Comment: It is likely that it is possible to do this by setting the parent anchor appropriately, but it would help a lot if you posted a code that answers can be based on.

Comment: Good point @abcdefg, editing my answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very basic version that accomplishes this. I kept it basic, but you can simplify things by playing with forest keys that inherit styles. The basic things are:

- use multipart nodes for the split schemes;
- use `append after command` in order to add the bullet;
- add a `special edge` style that accesses these bullet.

In practice, you need to use `s2l` or `s2r`, depending on whether the text is in the left or right cell, respectively, and you need to add `\nodepart{two}` at the end or beginning of the contents. Then you need to specify the cell the edge is supposed to start with `special edge=one` or `special edge=two`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\tikzset{s2/.style={rectangle split,rectangle split horizontal,
    rectangle split parts=2,draw},
    sd/.style={append after command={%
    (\tikzlastnode.#1 south|-\tikzlastnode.center)
    coordinate[circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,alias=\tikzlastnode-cheat]}},
    s2l/.style={s2,sd=two},
    s2r/.style={s2,sd=one},
    c/.style={circle,draw,fill=gray,minimum size=1em}}

\forestset{special edge/.style={edge path'/.expanded={
(!u.#1 south|-!u.center) -- (.child anchor)
},edge=-stealth}}

\begin{document}


\begin{forest}
    [,c
        [$\lnot B$\nodepart{two},s2l,
            [,c,special edge=two]
        ]
        [\nodepart{two}$C$,s2r
            [,c,special edge=one]
        ]
        [\nodepart{two}$\top$,s2r
            [,c,special edge=one]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you